# ARIMA daily forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

Say I want to make daily predictions for daily temperature data. I have 6 months of daily temperature data. What is the best procedure to both build an ARIMA model to make the predictions and improve the model as more data comes in?
I'm thinking of the following:

1. Find the best ARIMA(pdq) model parameters by doing nested cross validation on the 6 months of data currently available
2. make a 1 step forecast for tomorrow's temperature.

What happens after this? Do I need to retrain my model with the same pdq parameters with the new data point to find new coefficients? Do I need to retrain the whole model to find both the best pdq parameters and coefficients with the new 6 months + 1 day of data?

My confusion is that if I keep my model constant, then it will probably underperform when temperature changes happen that have not been accounted for by the model given the limited 6 months of data (e.g. when winter comes around).

Comment: Not sure what your expectations are. While Arima is powerful, it makes much more sense to get the weather forecast from a website via webscraping. Also 6 month data doesn't really help you. What "seasonality" do you expect from a half year model which doesn't even expirienced the seaonalit of 4 season at least once?

Comment: The weather was just an example. It's much more complex data about a business process

Comment: Ok then its a different story, but u still have to ask yourself what seasonality is to be expected. If your data does not provide it it wil perform really poorly when seasonality hits. Therefore, yes you propably should recalculate pdq each time. If you only have 1 timeseries, that shouldn't be a problem. If you want to do it for a portfolio of products it will require a lot more hardware usage, because you have to do ARIMA for each product.